# Fedora: System hangs after upgrade to FC18 (“started gdm”)

Tags: fedora, upgrade, gdm

I've been upgrading my eee laptop from Fedora 17 to 18. After a reboot the system shows up the boot message

```
[  OK  ] Started GNOME Display Manager.
```

and does not go on any further.

The system is alive, I can logon via ssh.

Any suggestions how to fix or debug this issue any further?

Thank you

Chris

```
[xxx@eee X11]$  lspci |grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D4xx/D5xx/N4xx/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, in my case the start of the `polkit` service failed.

A reinstall of this service made my system work:

```
yum reinstall polkit
```

Found it on http://ekuric.wordpress.com/2012/11/10/upgrade-to-fedora-18-aka-spherical-cow/#comment-135

Answer (score 0):

Try as root user (or use `sudo`):

```
yum distro-sync
```

Comment: hm, did not help in my case :(